# SalesforceIQ List import "Cannot import into this field"

Tags: contact, import

I added custom fields to the Contact Properties. The fields vary between multi-select, single select, and some text.

I'm trying to add new contacts to a List via csv Import including the custom Contact Properties. I can't seem to add the custom fields as they each say 
"Cannot import into this field". Any advice? I need to be able to import new contacts with all of these fields associated with them.

[image]